# Why does C++ have auto, rather than simply doing the right thing when there are no explicit type declarations?

Tags: c++, programming-languages

When `auto` was considered for addition to the C++ standard, was there any discussion of setting implicit types where there are no explicit declarations?  And if so, was the discussion recorded anywhere?

Not intended as a criticism.  Just curious from a PL perspective.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The `auto` keyword signals the compiler to use type inference to determine the type.  Are you asking why we need the `auto` keyword at all?  Because in C++ variable declarations are always preceded by something; otherwise the equals sign you use in your statement would be interpreted as an assignment, not a declaration.

Comment: To add to that, Rust and Swift uses `let`; Go uses `:=`; C#, Swift, Scala, Typescript, and Dart uses `var`; Scala also uses `val`. I think it is easier to parse if you put something before a variable declaration.

Comment: @Phyllostachys It's not so much that it's easier to parse, but simply put you can't catch misspelt variable names if you implicitly declare them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe such a possibility was ever considered by the C++ committee.

Further, although FORTRAN did have a sort-of implicit type system (variables starting with 'I' through 'N' were integers, everything else was real) I can't quite see how such a thing would work in a block-structured language like C++. For example, consider code like this:

```
int f() { 
    int i;

    if (something) {
        i = 2.0;
```

In C or C++ as currently defined the meaning of this is quite clear: the `i = 2.0` is taking `2.0`, converting it to `int`, and then assigning the resulting `2` to to the `i` that was declared at the outer scope.

If, however, you allowed the `auto` to be omitted, this would *apparently* define a new variable in the scope of the block controlled by the `if` statement, and that variable would (apparently) have type `double`, and the `i` at the outer scope would retain its previous value.

Now, I'll openly admit that depending on the implicit conversion from `double` to `int` here is probably a bad idea--but it's been part of the language for so long (decades) that it's effectively impossible to change it now.

In short, if you allowed the `auto` to be omitted, you'd almost certainly break some unknown (but almost certainly quite large) amount of existing code. Given the importance of backward compatibility in C++, this would be sufficiently unacceptable that I can't imagine the committee could ever give it any serious consideration.

Answer (score 9):

In 1963, Tony Hoare proposed adding implicit type rules to ALGOL.  The ALGOL committee boxed his ears, HARD.  Requiring variables to be declared explicitly was known, EVEN THEN, shown to reduce errors in programming.

Tony mentioned this in his Turing talk, and said it was BEFORE the probably-apocryphal Venus probe FORTRAN story, where a typo in a FORTRAN DO-statement instead created a brand-new variable and assigned it a value.  Various versions of that story float around: the most credible one says that it was caught in a review, and, if it had not been caught, would have resulted in the total loss of a (very expensive) spacecraft.

This was 53 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Allowing optional types where they used to be required can make the syntax ambiguous. It is easier to add a keyword (or to [reuse one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576953/c-auto-keyword-why-is-it-magic) in this case) than changing the grammar.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ syntax is designed in such a way that a declaration always needs a type to distinguish it from assignment. You simply cannot leave out the type, because that already has a different meaning:

```
int i = 1;
// Leaving out the type turns it into assignment:
i = 1;

int i;
// Leaving out the type turns it into evaluation:
i;
```

You simply *need* an *explicit* type annotation that tells the compiler that you don't want an explicit type. Sounds crazy, but that's what it is.

Other languages' syntax is designed differently, e.g. in Scala:

```
val i: Int = 10
// without type:
val i = 10
```